# Program don't encrypt the way I want (C language). From CS-50 lesson Vegenere

Tags: c, for-loop, encryption, cs50

Program must encrypt plaintext by the key from command-line.

If p is some plaintext and k is a keyword (i.e., an alphabetical string, whereby A (or a) represents 0, B (or b) represents 1, C (or c) represents 2, …, and Z (or z) represents 25), then each letter, ci, in the ciphertext, c, is computed as:

ci = (pi + kj) % 26

Note this cipher’s use of kj as opposed to just k. And if k is shorter than p, then the letters in k must be reused cyclically as many times as it takes to encrypt p.

In other words, if Vigenère himself wanted to say HELLO to someone confidentially, using a keyword of, say, ABC, he would encrypt the H with a key of 0 (i.e., A), the E with a key of 1 (i.e., B), and the first L with a key of 2 (i.e., C), at which point he’d be out of letters in the keyword, and so he’d reuse (part of) it to encrypt the second L with a key of 0 (i.e., A) again, and the O with a key of 1 (i.e., B) again. And so he’d write HELLO as HFNLP, per the below:
In that way:

```
plaintext       H   E   L   L   O

+key            A   B   C   A   B

(shift value)   0   1   2   0   1

= ciphertext    H   F   N   L   P
```

*For example:*

```
$ ./vigenere bacon

plaintext:  Meet me at the park at eleven am

ciphertext: Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz
```

*My case:*

**key:** baz

**plaintext:** barfoo

**expected:** caqgon

**my result:** caqfgv

My code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// Functions:
bool check_arguments(int argc);
bool is_key_alpha(string key);
int shift(char c);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (check_arguments(argc) == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Declaring key string variable:
    string key = argv[1];

    // Check containing any character that is not an alphabetic character
    if (is_key_alpha(key) == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Prompting user for plaintext:
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    
    // Ecipher:
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        if (islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", ((plaintext[i]) - 97 + shift(key[i])) % 26 + 97);
        }
        else if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", ((plaintext[i]) - 65 + shift(key[i])) % 26 + 65);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS :

// Checking if there's more than one command-line argument
// Checking if the command-line argument exists:
bool check_arguments(int argc)
{
    // Checking if there's more than one command-line argument
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n\n");
        return false;
    }
    // Checking if the command-line argument exists:
    else if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return false;
    }
    // If okey:
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// containing any character that is not an alphabetic character
bool is_key_alpha(string key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(key[i]) == false)
        {
            printf("Key contains non-alphabetical chars");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// convert character into the correct shift value
int shift(char c)
{ // for ex. char = a == 97 ascii
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        if (isupper(c))
        // The ASCII value of A is 65
        {
            c = c - 65;
        }
        else if (islower(c))
        // The ASCII value of a is 97
        {
            c = c - 97;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Notice that `key[i]` is undefined when `i >= 4` in your example. You probably meant `i%strlen(plaintext)` or something

Comment: Barry is on the right track. It _is_ UB. On my system, I got: `caqflr` Change: `shift(key[i])` into `shift(key[i % strlen(key)])`

Comment: _Side note:_ `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)` takes quadratic time (O(n^2)) to execute. Replace this with: `for (int i = 0; plaintext[i] != 0; i++)` which is only O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Barry is on the right track. It is UB. On my system, I got: `caqflr`

If `i` hits the length of `key`, then `key[i]` goes beyond the end of `key`

Change:

```
shift(key[i])
```

Into:

```
shift(key[i % strlen(key)])
```

---

That fixes the bug.

But, the code is more complicated than it needs to be. That may be one reason why the issue was difficult to spot.

Also, the code runs slowly.

---

Using `strlen` when looping on a string changes the running time from O(n) to O(n^2). That's because `strlen` rescans the string on every loop iteration.

So, to fix this, change (e.g.):

```
for (int i = 0;  i < strlen(plaintext);  ++i)
```

Into:

```
for (int i = 0;  plaintext[i] != 0;  ++i)
```

---

Also, in such loops there is a lot of replicated code using `plaintext[i]`.

Although the optimizer will understand this and produce fast code (i.e. cache the value and *not* refetch `plaintext[i]`), it can be simplified if we use an extra variable to contain the current value:

```
for (int i = 0, chr = plaintext[i];  chr != 0;  chr = plaintext[++i])
```

Now, instead of using `plaintext[i]` in many places within the loop we can use `chr`

This is usually easier to read. And, ironically, is close/similar to the code the optimizer will generate.

---

The length of the `key` is *invariant*. So, we can precompute the value and just use it rather than recalculating it on every iteration of the `plaintext` loop.

---

Avoid using "magic numbers":

1. When you want `'A'` use it instead of 65
2. When you want `'a'` use it instead of 97

---

Also, `shift` can be improved / eliminated:

1. Because `is_key_alpha` checks with `isalpha`, `key` is *guaranteed* to be only alpha chars. So, no need for `shift` to use `isalpha`
2. We don't need to keep the original `key` value, only the modified one. That is, we can replace every value in `key` with the result of `shift`
3. In other words, we only need to do the shift operation for each key once, during initialization. We can have `is_key_alpha` do this.

---

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// Functions:
bool check_arguments(int argc);
bool is_key_alpha(string key);
int shift(char c);

int
main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (check_arguments(argc) == false) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Declaring key string variable:
    string key = argv[1];

    // get the length of the key
    // (1) cache it so we don't need to call strlen(key) in the loop (it's
    //     invariant)
    // (2) because is_key_alpha transforms the key, calling strlen on key
    //     will no longer be valid
    int klen = strlen(key);

    // Check containing any character that is not an alphabetic character
    if (is_key_alpha(key) == false)
        return 1;

    // Prompting user for plaintext:
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // Ecipher:
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, chr = plaintext[i];  chr != 0; chr = plaintext[++i]) {
        int k = key[i % klen];

        if (islower(chr)) {
            chr = ((chr - 'a') + k) % 26 + 'a';
        }
        else if (isupper(chr)) {
            chr = ((chr - 'A') + k) % 26 + 'A';
        }

        printf("%c", chr);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS :

// Checking if there's more than one command-line argument
// Checking if the command-line argument exists:
bool
check_arguments(int argc)
{
    // Checking if there's more than one command-line argument
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n\n");
        return false;
    }
    // Checking if the command-line argument exists:
    else if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return false;
    }
    // If okey:
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

// containing any character that is not an alphabetic character
bool
is_key_alpha(string key)
{

    // do what shift does and convert the key into offsets
    for (int i = 0, chr = key[i];  chr != 0; chr = key[++i]) {
        if (isupper(chr)) {
            key[i] = chr - 'A';
            continue;
        }

        if (islower(chr)) {
            key[i] = chr - 'a';
            continue;
        }

        printf("Key contains non-alphabetical chars");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// convert character into the correct shift value
int
shift(char c)
{                                       // for ex. char = a == 97 ascii

    // The ASCII value of A is 65
    // The ASCII value of a is 97

    // NOTES:
    // (1) is_key_alpha guarantees that the key value is an alpha
    // (2) now that is_key_alpha computes the offset, this function is obsolete

    if (isupper(c))
        c -= 'A';
    else if (islower(c))
        c -= 'a';

    return c;
}
```

---

We can tighten this up a bit further. `shift` is no longer needed. And, we can have `is_key_alpha` return the key length (-1 is error). Now, that it changes the key, we could rename it to be more descriptive of its function

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// Functions:
bool check_arguments(int argc);
int key_transform(string key);

int
main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (check_arguments(argc) == false) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Declaring key string variable:
    string key = argv[1];

    // check and transform the key
    int klen = key_transform(key);
    if (klen < 0)
        return 1;

    // Prompting user for plaintext:
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // Ecipher:
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, chr = plaintext[i];  chr != 0; chr = plaintext[++i]) {
        int k = key[i % klen];

        if (islower(chr)) {
            chr = ((chr - 'a') + k) % 26 + 'a';
        }
        else if (isupper(chr)) {
            chr = ((chr - 'A') + k) % 26 + 'A';
        }

        printf("%c", chr);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS :

// Checking if there's more than one command-line argument
// Checking if the command-line argument exists:
bool
check_arguments(int argc)
{
    // Checking if there's more than one command-line argument
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n\n");
        return false;
    }
    // Checking if the command-line argument exists:
    else if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return false;
    }
    // If okey:
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

// check and transform the key
// RETURNS: key length (-1=error)
int
key_transform(string key)
{

    // do what shift does and convert the key into offsets
    int i = 0;
    for (int chr = key[i];  chr != 0;  chr = key[++i]) {
        if (isupper(chr)) {
            key[i] = chr - 'A';
            continue;
        }

        if (islower(chr)) {
            key[i] = chr - 'a';
            continue;
        }

        printf("Key contains non-alphabetical chars");
        return -1;
    }

    return i;
}
```